# Outlook Add-In: event when email is moved through inspector

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, mailitem

I need to change the category of a email when the inspector-window is closing - what I am doing with the `Close` event.

My problem is, if the user clicks "move to folder" in the inspector, the mail is moved, after this the close event is fired, but at this point I coannot change the mail any more, because it was changed trough the mail-move (eg: `EntryID` gets changed).

Any ideas?
An "before-Item-moved" event on the mail would be great - or a way to reload the changed mail.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to get folder that the email was moved to. Which means you'll have to use Redemption which has events for the RDOStore object that can detect changes to any folder.  But you'd also have to monitor EVERY store, because the user can obviously move it anywhere.  And because the EntryID has changed, you'd need to use PR_SEARCH_KEY as the unique identifier in order to even find the email and then apply the category to it.  Not fun!

Another option may be to repurpose the Move To Ribbon button to intercept the move operation, but then you'd have to provide your own folder picker!  Ugly!

Answer (score 1):

There is a BeforeMove event available:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorevents_10_event.beforemove%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: but this event only fires, when you move the mail in the explorer (eg by drag and drop) - but unfortunately NOT when you move it in the popup.

Comment: There's also a Folder before item move event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolderevents_12_event.beforeitemmove%28v=office.14%29.aspx  If that doesn't work then I'd just add a UserProperty to the mailitem called 'NotCategorized' and then unset it after your program successfully categorizes the mailitem.  You'd then have a periodic scan that checks the entire mailbox for any 'NotCategorized' items and process them

Comment: okay, yes. the inspector.beforeMove happens when the inspector itself is moved; the folder.beforeItemMove does happen when the user moves an item in the explorer (this does not happen when the user moves a mail in the inspector) regarding the userProperty:  that would maybe work - but it does have a very bad performance if you have to check the whole mailbox (with propably a couple of thousend mails in it)